# Rounding off decimal fraction in ios

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

```
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[format setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *temp = [format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:23.4451]];
NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```

I need round off a six decimal fraction number to two decimal. In iOS I tried the code above. I get the answer 23.5 when I give input as 23.45, but when I give input 23.445 the answer is 23.44.

Could someone clear-up "round half up" in iOS.

Comment: But I am getting correct answer for the input 23.45 as 23.45.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the way floats are represented in the computer.  You may be entering 23.445, but internally, it might be represented as something like 23.4449999, so it gets rounded down.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Interestingly, well at least to me, it *is* a float precision issue. As rdelmar had suggested in comments.

This problem can be avoided, at least at this precision level, by using a double. For example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[format setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[format setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

// With Float:
NSLog(@"%@",[format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:23.445]]); // Float
// Logs 23.44
NSLog(@"%@",[format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:23.445]]); // Double
// Logs 23.45
```

So you were not suffering from bad code, just imprecise variables.