# iOS Round Double value to 2 decimal digits and round 3rd decimal digit up

Tags: ios, double, rounding

I have I double value like this one `17.125`.
It should be rounded up to `17.13`

If I use the simple method like `%.2f` it shows me `17.12`
I also followed several methods described in other threads here like using `NumberFormatter` and so on - but without luck.

Maybe someone has an advice for me to fix this problem? Do I have to round it on my own?

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293754/rounding-off-decimal-fraction-in-ios

Comment: thank you! - works! fast and simple. I didn't stumble across this yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try This:

```
float number=17.125;
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[format setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *temp = [format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:number]];
NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```